# Langchain Agent Errors and Recommendations for chatbot (Error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting)

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I'm using langchain python because I'm working on creating a custom knowledge chatbot. I have created the vecstores and everything works fine until I introduced LangChain's agents.
The CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION works well but sometimes I get this error when asking query:
"`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 3 column 21 (char 52)`"

This is an example of what happens

`

```
Ask your question: suggest 2 vacation locations
response:


> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qais4\Desktop\chatbot test\tutor.py", line 372, in <module>
    run_terminal()
  File "C:\Users\qais4\Desktop\chatbot test\tutor.py", line 365, in run_terminal
    get_response(agent, question)
  File "C:\Users\qais4\Desktop\chatbot test\tutor.py", line 206, in get_response
    result = agent.run(question)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qais4\Desktop\chatbot test\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 236, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks)[self.output_keys[0]]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qais4\Desktop\chatbot test\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 140, in __call__
    raise e
```

This is how I set up the agent:

```
 agent = initialize_agent(
        agent=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
        tools=tools,
        llm=ChatLLM,
        verbose=True,
        memory=conversational_memory,
    )
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I pretty much tried all agent types but all of them get errors on some specific case. The only one without errors was CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION Agent type but that often makes bad decisions in terms of tools (choosing not to select knowledge base tool and saying "I dont know"). I have also tried following the examples on Langchain's documentation but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When I created a general python code executing agent using PythonREPLTool, if the code ended in a quotation mark then that would be removed and the code would return an error. The quotation mark is removed possibly during json formatting.
For example if my query was "Save some text as a string variable" then the agent would return the response
variable = "some text"
and the last quotation mark would be removed and python would return an error.
My solution was to add this text to the end of the query: "add a hashtag # to the end of the code."